# JSON.parse() not working in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

The JS native method `JSON.parse()` appears to be malfunctioning in Google Apps Script.

Code.gs

```
const run = () => {
  const result = JSON.parse('{"foo": "bar"}');
  Logger.log( 'result: %s', result, );
  return result;
}
```

Throws:

> TypeError: JSON.parse is not a function at run

Is this a bug with Google Apps Script? Or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: I also get a similar error when I try `JSON.stringify({foo: "bar"})`

Comment: Works fine for me. Test it in a new project..(Make sure you haven't reassigned `JSON` to something else)

Comment: @TheMaster: That was it. I had reassigned it. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary from comments:

Make sure you haven't reassigned `JSON` to something else.